RTL direction with punctuation not working well on - POI word packages
I have struggled with that much time and didn't find solution yet.
I have some text that I'm injecting into a word file by POI xwpf package.
It's in Hebrew - an RTL language, and the punctuation like dot, or comma, should be in the left side of the row, and not on the right.
I did some solutions that guiding how to style the text like that but it didn't set the order well, only align it to the right. See image below.
(I have used STOnOff1 according to this answer)
My POC code:
package yimprogramming.lotem.wordtoword.test;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.sharedTypes.STOnOff1;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTP;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPPr;

public class RtlPoiProblem {

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Show rtl problem: ");
        demoRtl1();
        
        
    }
    public static void demoRtl1() {
        
        XWPFDocument doc= new XWPFDocument();

          XWPFParagraph paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
          XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
          run.setText("Paragraph 1 LTR");

          paragraph = doc.createParagraph();

          CTP ctp = paragraph.getCTP();
          CTPPr ctppr;
          if ((ctppr = ctp.getPPr()) == null) ctppr = ctp.addNewPPr();
          ctppr.addNewBidi().setVal(STOnOff1.ON);

          run = paragraph.createRun();
//        run.setText("السلام عليكم");
          run.setText("נקודה אחרי.");


          paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
          run = paragraph.createRun();
          run.setText("Paragraph 3 LTR");
            
          FileOutputStream out;
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream("WordDocument.docx");
             doc.write(out);
              out.close();
              doc.close();  
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         
        
    }
}

Result:

My pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>yimprogramming.word2word</groupId>
    <artifactId>word-to-word</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Word Files Generator</name>
    <description>Program that creates New description word files from exist data . </description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <!--<version>1.18.30</version> -->
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- For word parsing -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.5</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>




    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>


                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>

                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>
                                ${project.build.directory}/libs
                            </outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>libs/</classpathPrefix>
                            <!-- Here comes the main class -->
                            <mainClass>
                                yimprogramming.lotem.wordtoword.WordFilesGeneratorApplication
                            </mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


Why not run.setText(".נקודה אחרי");?

Because it's just an example. The actual data come from other files, it contains large paragraphs with many lines and commas at at the middle.
like that for example:
"
קורס פיתוח מנהלים דרג מתקדם -הכשרה מקצועית למנהלים בדרג ביניים במשרד האוצר (כ-20 משתתפים). פיתוח, תכנון והנחיה, תפעול וארגון פעילויות הדרכה, ליווי והנחיית המפגשים עצמם. בנוסף התקיימה עבודה מול ספקים."
I don't think it's a good practice to start parse it, and I don't sure if it's possible at all.

See bidirectional with word document using Aphace POI.
If HebrewTextFile.txt contains:
שלום עולם!
זה עובד טוב מאוד עכשיו.

קורס פיתוח מנהלים דרג מתקדם -הכשרה מקצועית למנהלים בדרג ביניים במשרד האוצר (כ-20 משתתפים). פיתוח, תכנון והנחיה, תפעול וארגון פעילויות הדרכה, ליווי והנחיית המפגשים עצמם. בנוסף התקיימה עבודה מול ספקים.

...then following code...
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTP;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPPr;
//import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STOnOff;

import java.util.List;

public class CreateWordRTLParagraphsFromFile {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(new File("HebrewTextFile.txt").toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_16);

  XWPFDocument doc= new XWPFDocument();

  for (String line : lines) {

   XWPFParagraph paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
   CTP ctp = paragraph.getCTP();
   CTPPr ctppr = ctp.getPPr();
   if (ctppr == null) ctppr = ctp.addNewPPr();
   //ctppr.addNewBidi().setVal(STOnOff.ON);
   ctppr.addNewBidi().setVal(true);

   XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
   run.setText("\u202E" + line + "\u202C");

  }

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./WordDocument.docx");
  doc.write(out);
  out.close();
  doc.close();

 }
}

...results in:


Thanks!
What you have suggested is working.
The only problem is that inner digits, and English section also become RTL (as you can see in the example you did "20" become to "02").
Is there are some marks that exclude rtl from not-rtl letters or I must parse this by myself, and insert the digits and the English inside ltr marks?

@lingar: "you did "20" become to "02"": Yes, LTR "20" become RTL "02". That's consequent, isn't it? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61169497/bidirectional-with-word-document-using-aphace-poi/61170607#61170607 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_text#Table_of_possible_BiDi_character_types. These are the possibilities you have.
